# C++ - Redefinition/Previously defined error

Tags: c++, object

**Why am I getting this error? I'm just making a class object. What am I missing?**

Is it because of the empty body methods and constructor? I'm not sure here.

The tutorial im using is from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkwX7FkLfug

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Neuron {};

typedef std::vector<Neuron> Layer;

class Net
{
public:
  Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology) {};
  void feedForward(const std::vector<double> &inputVals) {};
  void backProp(const std::vector<double> &targetVals) {};
  void getResults(std::vector<double> &resultVals) const {};
private:
  // [layerNum][neuronNum]
  std::vector<Layer> m_layers;
};

void Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology)
{
  unsigned numLayers = topology.size();
  for (unsigned layerNum = 0; layerNum < numLayers; ++layerNum){
    m_layers.push_back(Layer());

    for (unsigned neuronNum = 0; neuronNum <= topology[layerNum]; ++neuronNum){
      m_layers.back().push_back(Neuron());
      std::cout << "Made a neuron!" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<unsigned> topology;
  topology.push_back(3);
  topology.push_back(2);
  topology.push_back(1);
  Net myNet(topology);

  std::vector<double> inputVals;
  myNet.feedForward(inputVals);

  std::vector<double> targetVals;
  myNet.backProp(targetVals);

  std::vector<double> resultVals;
  myNet.getResults(resultVals);
  return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
g++ e:/something/ProgrammingExt/0a_Testing/cpp/neural_network/neural-net-tutorial.cpp
```

Getting this error:

```
ERROR (0.39 seconds): e:/something/ProgrammingExt/0a_Testing/cpp/neural_network/neural-net-

tutorial.cpp:20:52: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
 void Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology)
                                                    ^
e:/something/ProgrammingExt/0a_Testing/cpp/neural_network/neural-net-tutorial.cpp:20:6: error: redefinition of ’Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned int>&)’
 void Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology)
      ^~~
e:/something/0a_Testing/cpp/neural_network/neural-net-tutorial.cpp:11:3: note: ’Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned int>&)’ previously defined here
   Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology) {};
   ^~~
```

Comment: It is because (1) you have 2 different definitions of your constructor `Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned>&)` and (2) your constructor signature in the second definition is invalid (it has return type void, but should have no return type);

Comment: Another problem is that two bodies are given for the constructor

Comment: You have two distinct definitions for the constructor `Net::Net()` - hence the redefinition error.     The second (following the class definition) has a return type of `void` - constructors are not permitted to have ANY return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages tell you why you are getting them.

> ```
> ERROR (0.39 seconds): [path]/neural-net-tutorial.cpp:20:52: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
>  void Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology)
>                                                     ^
> ```

This is the first error. Constructors return nothing, not even `void`. So drop the `void` keyword from the indicated line.

> ```
> [path]/neural-net-tutorial.cpp:20:6: error: redefinition of ’Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned int>&)’
>  void Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology)
>       ^~~
> [path]/neural-net-tutorial.cpp:11:3: note: ’Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned int>&)’ previously defined here
>    Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology) {};
>    ^~~
> ```

This is the second error. You have two definitions of the constructor for `Net` that takes a `const std::vector<unsigned> &` parameter. The duplicate is on line 20, the same line that triggered the earlier error about `void`. The original is on line 11, where you defined the constructor to have an empty body. There is an extraneous semicolon after this definition, which suggests there might have been an intent to convert the definition to a declaration at some point. That point is now. *(The `6` and `3` in the error messages are positions within the indicated line. Your compiler decided to mark the errors at the start of the constructor's name.)*

Since you apparently do not want this constructor to have an empty body, change the definition on line 11 from

```
   Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology) {};
```

to a declaration by dropping the function body:

```
   Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology);
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you for the explanation! The second error is the real problem, I added void just to see if it solved anything because I assumed that my object should have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

C++ overloading can't be based on return type. So there are two functions with exact same argument and they are treated as the same function:

```
Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology) {};
```

and

```
void Net::Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology)
{
  unsigned numLayers = topology.size();
  for (unsigned layerNum = 0; layerNum < numLayers; ++layerNum){
    m_layers.push_back(Layer());

    for (unsigned neuronNum = 0; neuronNum <= topology[layerNum]; ++neuronNum){
      m_layers.back().push_back(Neuron());
      std::cout << "Made a neuron!" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

That's why you got redefinition error.

Another problem is that constructor doesn't have a return type, but you give it a "void" for the second definition. That's why you got the first error:
tutorial.cpp:20:52: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
 void Net::Net(const std::vector &topology)